# Favicon different from Earth Science?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, diseño, favicon

Our favicon is used in various places around the Stack Exchange (SE) network, to identify the site.
Currently, it's [image: ESblue2] for main and [image: ESblack2]  for meta.
The problem I see is that these are awfully similar to those for Earth Science.SE,
which are [image: ESblue] for main and [image: ESblack] for meta.

The larger versions offer slight differences, but it's still hard to tell quickly which is which (power users on this site, did you guess right, even after some time to think about it?):

- [image] for main and [image] for meta.
- [image] for main and [image] for meta.

Should SE visually distinguish between the two very different sites?

---

*(Discussion on Earth Science Meta is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285456/favicon-of-earth-science-and-spanish-are-too-similar-exactly-the-same-in-hnq-li)).*

Comment: Marking as completed following the discussion in [Do we want a different favicon for Spanish Language?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/1674)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92180/discussion-on-question-by-wbt-favicon-different-from-earth-science).

Comment: Update: [New design launched](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/30873) (which includes a redesigned `ñ` favicon!)