# Do we want a different favicon for Spanish Language?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, diseño, favicon

Currently both Spanish Language and Earth Science have a favicon that is almost the same (see Meta.SE [Favicon of Earth Science and Spanish are too similar (exactly the same in HNQ list)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285456/209901) and [Earth Science vs. Spanish Language favicons: now with 0% lowercasing!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325487/209901)).

While we are in Beta, we are supposedly not allowed to have our own style of icons. However, it is clear that the current situation makes both sites difficult to distinguish.

Prompted by CM Catija's comment:

> If these sites want different icons that are still Unicode, that discussion needs to happen on their respective sites. It's not for MSE to decide if this should be changed and, if so, to what. I recognize that this question was originally asked on a child meta and that it was migrated here because it was about two sites. But the question isn't "should these be more different" the question is "do we want something else?" – [Catija♦ Mar 20 at 18:51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285456/favicon-of-earth-science-and-spanish-are-too-similar-exactly-the-same-in-hnq-li#comment1062705_285456)

I ask here: do we want a different icon? If so, which one?

Comment: To be clear, this isn't a design. This would be similar to what you see for the logos on [anime.se] or [buddhism.se]. It's a Unicode symbol that would be used in place of the "Es" you currently have but the icon would otherwise be the same. It needs to be something that you think would be recognized as being relevant to your site in the way the initials we use by default are.

Comment: Thanks @Catija this makes me think that something like a big _Ñ_ would very much help in this case. Let's see what others thing, but to me this can be an interesting approach, as it is a very specific Spanish letter (it is used in other languages, but they are quite smaller, so they are not likely to match any other SE site).

Comment: Didn't we try to get a Favicon before and it was denied? I seem to remember Charlie creating one. That thread must be deleted now. I'm just asking because I think that this is a good idea, but I want to make sure that if we suggest something it has a good chance of being accepted. My understanding is that this might be possible but changing the unicode character, not changing to something else. I know that other beta sites have their own favicon (like the chess stack). So what are exactly our possibilities in terms of favicons?

Comment: @Diego yes, we tried some time ago (I offered a bounty to [a Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285456/209901) also), but we did not get much attention. Now that [walen noticed that favicons in HNQ are equal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325487/209901) and got quite a lot of attention, we can try this again. We have a CM commenting on the question, so this is a good starting point : )

Comment: @Diego yes, the arrogant Charlie of the past once tried to create a favicon for [Spanish.SE], but that was way before I learnt about the rules of the beta sites. Que me vine muy arriba, vamos.

Comment: @Charlie haha! Still, your suggested favicon was received with a lot of upvotes in [my answer in Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285489/209901). So it was good that you overlooked the beta sites rules :P

Comment: @Diego I suspect the [Chess SE's](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) icon is also a unicode symbol: `♖` (like [Buddhism and Anime & Manga's](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/do-we-want-a-different-favicon-for-spanish-language#comment5694_3052))

Comment: @Diego There are thousands of Unicode characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters The chess symbol is one of them. So, for this to be accepted, y'all will need to pick something that we could use as if it were text. This makes it easier on you because there's no "art" or "design" to it. You pick something that already exists and we plop it on the icon.

Comment: @Charlie for what it's worth I liked your SO inspired logo.

Comment: @ukemi we have already talked with the CM about this, so the request is on status-hopefully-ontheirway

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from last week: [Custom Spanish Language design and logo - Information gathering](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448/30873) :)

Comment: Update: [New design launched](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/30873) (which includes a redesigned `ñ` favicon!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would definitely favor an `ñ` favicon. `Ñ` would be OK too, but lowercase fits better. [Both are Unicode characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f1/index.htm).

I don't want to bother any of you explaining how and why the letter Ñ is essentially the symbol of the Spanish language; it's already been discussed in the linked posts, and one need only read not even the Spanish but the [*English* Wikipedia entry for **Ñ**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%91) to see that this letter's history is tied to that of our language, and that most (if not all) of the other languages that use Ñ do so influenced by Spanish use (or because computers lacked the actual non-latin1 letters and they had to make do with an Ñ as the closest one).

It is true, however, that the tilde might not render clearly at low resolutions, depending on the font used, existence of aliasing etc.
A 1-pixel-wide `ñ` renders quite clearly, IMO: [image]
That favicon was done pixel by pixel in Paint by me, trying to resemble the 1-pixel-wide `ES` letters currently used in the smallest icon. I don't know whether StackExchange's way of generating Unicode favicons allows for such a clear tilde in such a small size, but I hope it does. Also, I don't think the "big" favicon would have this problem.

If a `ñ` favicon is somehow not doable, other distinctive Spanish symbols are the opening question mark `¿` ([info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bf/index.htm)) and opening exclamation mark `¡` ([info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a1/index.htm)).
A favicon made with some combination of these (`¿?` `¡!` `¡¿` `¿¡`) would probably be distinct enough, but I don't think most people would identify it as being related to the Spanish language.

**TL;DR: Yes, I want a different favicon, one with a lowercase `ñ`.**

Comment: I agree, the `ñ` clearly and simply represents the language. And according to [Catija's comment](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/do-we-want-a-different-favicon-for-spanish-language?cb=1#comment5692_3051), the beta favicons are rendered using unicode symbols (e.g. `☸`, `画`), so there should be no issue using an enye.

Comment: I also like the idea of having a **ñ** (lowercase) as the Stack's favicon. Although it is not exclusive to it, I believe many people will immediately relate such an icon with the Spanish language.

Comment: We've made this change as requested. Congrats!

Answer (score 2):

To give another option its own place to be voted on, the inverted question mark (a distinguishing feature of the Spanish orthography, which also embodies the idea of SE being a **Q**&A site).

Either singular:

> ## ¿

or as a pair:

> ## ¿?

Comment: I must downvote it, I don't think it is representative enough of the Spanish language... let's have a `ñ` instead!

Comment: I upvoted.  I like ñ but I like ¿ even better, because I think that a tiny ñ will be harder to see and understand than ¿ .

Comment: What's more, this is a questions site, so this one is nice.

Answer (score 1):

I like [walen's proposal](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3052/12637), but just to give people the other obvious choice to vote:

**Yes, I want a different favicon, one with an uppercase `Ñ`.**

<sub>Ñ is U+00D1 in Unicode, `&Ntilde;` in HTML.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

## Why such dull blue & white colours?

Cambiando los colores a aquellos de la bandera española, sería mucho más llamativo e  identificador.

[image]

A cambio, blanco sobre azul cielo apenas da contraste e aún menos en un fávicon minúsculo.

[image]

Los japoneses hicieron algo similar:

[image: Japanes]

Comment: Spanish.SE está en un estado llamado "[design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/643262)". Esto quiere decir que, aunque ya no estamos en "beta", todavía no tenemos un diseño (estilo) propio. El estilo del sitio es igual que el de todos los sitios en beta. Esto quiere decir, entre otras cosas, que nuestro favicon tiene que ser azul con texto blanco, y lo único que pudimos elegir es el símbolo (Unicode) que hay en el favicon.

Comment: Cuando pasemos a la fase "2", Stack Exchange nos dará un estilo propio que incluirá un icono más individual. Normalmente, el icono individual lo elige un diseñador profesional, y mi impresión es que la comunidad no tiene mucho poder de decisión en el tema. [Aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359131/643262) puedes ver el significado y motivación de los logos de otros sitios.

Comment: @wimi creo que lo de _design-independent graduation_ no es exactamente lo que se implementó en este y los otros sitios al que se los [sacó de Beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128/1674) y no sé hasta qué punto esa publicación de Meta.SE que referencias sigue siendo vigente. Aquí, las elecciones son un híbrido, no tenemos rutas de migración, sí hay anuncios de promoción de comunidad (que ya no dependen del estatus), los umbrales de reputación son los mismos que antes. Básicamente, se quitó la etiqueta de _beta_. En cualquier caso, ¡sí estaría bien que algún día tuviéramos diseño!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' ya veo. Entonces, aún menos cosas que en "design-independent graduation"... En cualquier caso, no tiene mucho sentido discutir sobre el icono porque no hay ningún escenario en el que podemos elegirlo...

Comment: Aparte de lo que ya se ha comentado, decir además que considero un error identificar el idioma español con los colores de la bandera de España, teniendo en cuenta que España es solo uno entre una multitud de países que cuentan con el español como idioma oficial. Se puede argumentar que España es el país de origen del idioma, pero aun así dudo que la gente en Hispanoamérica se sintiera identificada con este cambio.