# Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!

Tags: discusión, beta

**This site started private beta before July 2012, so it is no longer "beta", it is a full site by our definition**. We've removed the word "beta" from your site banner because we believe that you aren't really a beta site any more, even if you don't get ten questions per day.

[image: Banner that reads "Congratulations" in three-dimensional white text with red, yellow and blue confetti.]

What this means for you:

- the "Beta" is removed from your banner
- the site is moved to the "[Launched](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched)" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
- retain beta reputation levels
- Your currently scheduled election is still a pro-tem election but we will schedule full-site elections no sooner than 6 months after it ends

This is the start of a process that we are already discussing internally and will be bringing to the network for public discussion once the plan is finalized. My hope is that this will mean the end of the monolith we currently refer to as "Graduation" in favor of a well-defined set of small targets to achieve the various elements that made up "Graduation".

I'm sure you have many questions, please feel free to ask and I'll answer what I can. It helps me out a lot if you can limit answers to focus on a single question/subject rather than asking a dozen questions in one answer.

Please feel free to [follow the MSE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) for more background on this decision. You can ask questions either here or there; I'll try to keep up with all of them. Your mods also have some info, so they may be answering in my stead.

Thanks so much for your patience and stay tuned!

Comment: Congratulations to us!  Let the trumpets blare!  Catija, thanks for the good news!

Comment: Related SE-wide meta question by fedorqui: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331736/287826

Answer (score 3):

Welcome back, Catija!  You always bring good news!

I've got a question. Since we're now a "graduated" site, **will we be able to include other graduated sites in the migration paths for questions**?

From time to time we get questions meant for es.StackOverflow. We also get some that are a better fit for ELL, Writing, Linguistics, Literature...
Alas, if we pick *Off-topic > Belongs to another site*, our only target for migration is our own Meta. So we are forced to either:

- raise a custom mod flag asking for migration (which cannot be voted upon) and/or wait for a mod to do the migration themself;
- VTC as off-topic and leave a comment to OP telling them that their question would get better answers at XYZ.SE and to post it there instead.

Being able to pick other sites as targets for migration and making this an integral part of our queue review process would be really nice :)

Comment: [Not yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331751/209901).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, this is how the site was doing the last day it was in Beta mode in Area 51 (in https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language):

[image]

Some important dates:

- It was proposed by [juanformoso](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/38/juanformoso) on July 22, 2010,
- Private Beta started on November 15, 2011
- Public Beta started after a week, on November 22, 2011
- End of Beta (graduation?) occurred on August 1, 2019

Top 10 users when Beta ended:

- Charlie 52k
- Diego 37k
- guifa 28k
- pablodf76 25k
- fedorqui 20k
- walen 20k
- Rodrigo 13k
- ukemi 13k
- Gustavson 11k
- jrdioko 9k