# Do we need a migration target to Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: discusión, votos-de-cierre, migración

The title says it all really. At the moment we have only one migration target - our meta. I have noticed that we do occasionally get programming questions and today I voted to close one as not about the Spanish language when really it would have made more sense to vote for migration.

Comment: Also discussed in [Congratulations, you're no longer in Beta!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128/1674)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why we do not have any migration targets (apart from our Meta) is that we are still "partially" in Beta. Our "Beta" label was removed as part of [this initiative](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/643262), but we got only some of the privileges of graduated sites:

> - have the "Beta" removed from their banner
> - be moved to the "Launched" sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar
> - [...]
> - have their full-site elections delayed, but scheduled eventually

Other characteristics of graduated sites were not provided to us (emphasis mine):

> - There is no unique design,
> - **They have no community migration pathes** [sic],
> - The privilege reputation levels are like on the betas

[SE staff said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/643262) that this partial migration was

> the start of a process that we are already discussing internally and will be bringing to the network for public discussion once the plan is finalized

but nothing seems to have happened since then. Migration paths can only be added by SE staff, and the criteria [seem to be pretty strict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261200/643262). When (if) our graduation process is completed, I assume we will get a proper list of migration paths, which should, if anything, include Stack Overflow en español (11 migrations from Spanish.SE to there in the last 7 years), and maybe Language Learning (5 migrations).

Of course, in obvious cases, you can always flag for moderator attention and say that it belongs on another site. If the question also looks like it is well asked and would be well received on the target site, I will be happy to do the migration.